# Basic Spring MVC project not serving view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having some trouble getting my Spring MVC project to serve a view to my localhost.  I created a project from within Spring Tool Suite using the New -> Spring Project -> Spring MVC Project option.  I have not modified this code at all, as I'm confident that this should work the way it is (but obviously it isn't).

**Here is my project structure and `HomeController.java`**

[image]

This theoretically should bring up `home.jsp` when I go to localhost, but instead brings up the basic Pivotal server page:

[image]

In my `HomeController.java` file, if I change the `@RequestMapping(value)` to "/testing", I get a 404 error:

[image]

Finally, here is my `ServletContext.xml` (which contains my ViewResolver that came with the Spring MVC Project template):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="pear.pear.pear" />
</beans:beans>
```

**And my web.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

How can I resolve this issue?  What am I doing wrong?  Also, on a side note, I've noticed in many other Spring tutorials that they use an `Application.java` driver class - is that necessary?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Darshan Just edited my post and added that file in.

Comment: you have no index, default or any other welcome file, hence when you fire `localhost:8080\testing`, it does not find anything hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is probably not running on the root URL in Tomcat (/). the default would be the same name as the project, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/hello/testing`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  So would I be correct in assuming that having an `Application.java` driver class is not necessary for Spring applications?

Comment: Not necessary, and not used if you are deploying into an external container like that. It's a useful option (at least at dev time) though.

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt - 1:** Change the context root defined in Project-->Properties-->Web Project Settings to "/" and restart the server (this did not work)

**Attempt - 2:** Locate the server.xml used by vfabric server and change the value "/" for your docbase and restart the server viola it worked !

**Screenshot**
[image: Context Path In server.xml]

It's funny when a spring MVC project is created with STS the tool automatically assigns the last few characters of the package structure you enter while creating the toplevelpackage as the context path for your web application, in your case if you access the web project with **`http://localhost:8080/pear`** you would be able to load the home page.

Comment: Ahh what a silly mistake!  Thank you.  So I take it that an `Application.java` driver class is unneccesary?